# Can i use HAVING clause with <> operator in MDX of row axis

Tags: mdx, having

I am getting the error shown below while executing my MDX query.

I am using `HAVING` to filter out `[Accessories]` from `English Product Category Name`

```
SELECT 
  {
      (
        [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2001]
      : 
        [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2004]
      )
    - 
      [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2003]
  } ON 0
 ,{
    [Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].[English Product Category Name]
  } HAVING 
    [Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].MEMBERS
  <> 
    [Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].&[Accessories] ON 1
FROM [CubeForMDXReports];
```

**Executing the query ...

> Query (10, 1) The NotEqualTo function expects a string or numeric expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used.
>   Execution complete**

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do this in the `HAVING` clause:

```
[Set] <> [Member]
```

Hence the exception.

You could just use Except to ignore accessories:

```
SELECT 
  {
      (
        [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2001]
      : 
        [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2004]
      )
    - 
      [Ship Date].[Hierarchy].[Calendar Year].&[2003]
  } ON 0
 ,Descendants
  (
    Except
    (
      [Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].MEMBERS
     ,[Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].&[Accessories]
    )
   ,[Dim Product Category].[English Product Category Name].[English Product Category Name]
  ) ON 1
FROM [CubeForMDXReports];
```

Comment: @tibco29 great, glad it helped - feel free to mark this as the answer, or up it to 1 if you feel inclined.